# Combine columns in a rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

I'm writing an ActiveRecord migration to split a single name attribute into first and last names.  I think the schema-altering part below is correct, but can I use the migration to transfer existing data as well?

The reversion case is pretty simple- we'd combine the contents of first_name & last_name, separated by a space. For the splitting, we could split name on the first instance of whitespace and save the halves to first_name & last_name. (I know this is a shaky assumption and that names are fussy- but it will take care of most cases, and the remainder can be fixed manually).

```
class BreakUpNameColumnInAddressBook < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :shipping_addresses, :first_name, :string
    add_column :shipping_addresses, :last_name, :string
    remove_column :shipping_addresses, :name
  end

  def down
    add_column :shipping_addresses, :name, :string
    remove_column :shipping_addresses, :first_name
    remove_column :shipping_addresses, :last_name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run any code you like in a migration so just do what you need to do (untested, be careful):

```
class BreakUpNameColumnInAddressBook < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :shipping_addresses, :first_name, :string
    add_column :shipping_addresses, :last_name, :string

    ShippingAddress.all.each do |address|
      fn, ln = address.name.split(' ', 2)
      address.update(first_name: fn, last_name: ln)
    end

    remove_column :shipping_addresses, :name
  end

  def down
    add_column :shipping_addresses, :name, :string

    ShippingAddress.all.each do |address|
      n = [address.first_name, address.last_name].join(' ')
      address.update(name: n)
    end

    remove_column :shipping_addresses, :first_name
    remove_column :shipping_addresses, :last_name
  end
end
```

[Split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-split) method splits the string into (at most) two chunks after the first occurrence of whitespace. [Join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-join) method merges the elements of the array putting the space in between them.

Comment: It's a bad practice to use models in migrations since your code will evolve (e.g. your model might disappear or get renamed someday). But as [this article describes](http://blog.makandra.com/2010/03/how-to-use-models-in-your-migrations-without-killing-kittens/) you can inline the model classes and you are making sure the migration will run even when the model disappeared. Just (re)define the `ShippingAddress` model in the migration class to be future-proof.